# Anaconda not launching

Tags: anaconda3

Whenever I try to run Anaconda Navigator (or Spyder), either from cmd or from windows, it does not launch. My mousepointer briefly shows that it is loading, but then nothing happens.

I have tried a number of solutions from other posts, but nothing worked:

- I have completely uninstalled and reinstalled Anaconda
- I have tried `conda update -n root conda` + `conda update --all`
- I have tried `conda clean --packages && conda clean --all && conda update --all`
- I have tried `anaconda-navigator --reset`

and a few more things.

My issue looks as follows:
[image]

Comment: see this discussion as well: https://community.anaconda.cloud/t/anaconda-not-launching/34440/5

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution by itself, but: PyQt5 is bundled with Anaconda by default, so you shouldn't need to install it (again). In order to verify the presence of PyQt5:

a) execute `conda list` in the `base` environment and search for the package `pyqt`.

b) launch Spyder in the `base` environment and execute the following code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel

app = QApplication([])
label = QLabel("Hello World!")
label.show()

app.exec_()
```

This should open an application window with the text "Hello World!".

Both would indicate, that PyQt5 is installed, and that the problem lies elsewhere.

Credit goes to JKSH for his answer to [ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: The specified module could not be found.](https://forum.qt.io/topic/118934/importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-qtcore-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found/2)